# How to make Orage Calendar application stay below the active window?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, window

I am using XUBUNTU.

I am using the **orage** calendar application set up like a widget on my desktop.

However, whenever I open any window of any application, this widget always stays on top and hides sections of the active application.

Is there a way to avoid this and make sure that orage widget always stays below the active window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### orage calendar app

[image]

This is a smart lightweight calendar app perfect to keep on your desktop.

If not already installed:

#### [orage](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/orage) [image: Install orage]

There are a number of options you can configure in the preferences for this application.

These are in its *preferences*.  Choose from the menu *Edit --> Preferences*

Click the *Display Settings* tab and untick the option shown in the image:

[image]

Once done, any application launched or moved over Orage will not be hidden by it.

Personally I would also use the *systray* option in this same tab.

[image]

Using this option you can make the widget visible or hide it by just clicking the system-tray applet.